# Partitioning of a set w.r.t. injectivity

Tags: math, combinatorics

I have two disjoint sets **A** and **B** which are merged into a set **C**=**A**+**B** which is then partitioned. The number of such partitions is the nth [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number). I want to filter out the partitions to be **injective**, i.e. items from each set are not merged with items from the same set, and then figure out if this significantly reduces the number of such partitions.

For example, if

- **A**={1,2}
- **B**={3}

Then: **C** = {1,2,3} and the partitions of **C** are 5:

```
{ {1}, {2}, {3} }

{ {1, 2}, {3} }

{ {1, 3}, {2} }

{ {1}, {2, 3} }

{ {1, 2, 3} }
```

However, the 2nd and the 5th partitions have 1 and 2 merged, which I want to filter out, so in this case the number I am looking for is 3 instead of 5. Anyone knows how to calculate this restricted reccurence?

Comment: I have the impression that you might have a higher success rate with this question over at "Computational Science" http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Or perhaps stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all off the top of my head, so caveat emptor!

I'll call an injective partition a split, for brevity.

Each element (i.e. subset of A union B) in a split can itself have at most two elements (at most 1 from A and at most 1 from B and all elements are either from A or from  B); it also must have at least one element. If two splits have the same set of 2 element sets ('pairs') then they must be the same (all the other sets are singletons whose union is A union B less the union of the pairs). A split can have at most min(card(A), card(B)) pairs, or we'd have run out of one or tother of A or B.

To count these, let S(m,n) be the number of splits when A has m elements and B has n. Given an element a of A, we can divide  the splits into two disjoint subsets: those where a occurs in a pair, and those where it doesn't. The latter set is in 1-1 correspondence with the splits of A \ {a} and B. To count the former, the partner of a -- the other element of the pair a is in -- can be any element b of B, and the rest of the split is a split of A \ {a} and B \ {b}. So we have the recursion

```
S(m,n) = S(m-1, n) + n * S(m-1, n-1)
```

Finally, to get the recursion started

```
S(1,n) = 1 + n
```

(we have either no pairs -- 1 -- or 1 pair which can be {1,b} for any of the n elements of B

Comment: Thanks, that made a lot of sense. Also `S(m,1)=1+m` and `S(0,n)=S(m,0)=1`

Answer (score 0):

Partitions of **C** which fulfill your restrictions must have following properties:

1. Each partition in **C** can have only one or two elements, otherwise there will be two elements both from **A** or **B**.
2. If partition from **C** have two elements, then one is from **A** and one from **B**.

Such partitions represents some [matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) in complete bipartite graph with sets **A** and **B**. Partition with two elements represent edge, and partition with one element represent unmatched vertex.

So, you are interested in number of different matchings in complete bipartite graph **K<sub>|A|,|B|</sub>**.